# how to get all the records from mysql table in codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I try the following code but only one recorde will come

```
function redeem()
{
    $this->db->select('questionEng');
    $this->db->from('question');
    $query=$this->db->get();
    foreach($query->result_array() as $result)
    {
        print_r($result);die;
    }
    $this->load->view('admin/redeem');
}
```

Only one record is coming.please help me

Comment: die(); outside of foreach

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function redeem()
{
    $this->db->select('questionEng');
    $this->db->from('question');
    $results  =  $this->db->get()->result_array();
    foreach($results as $result)
    {
        echo "<pre>";
        print_r($result);
        echo "<pre>";
    }
    die;
    $this->load->view('admin/redeem');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code you have used die in for loop. So you script will stop working after first looping. So you script printing only one record.

```
function redeem()
{
    $this->db->select('questionEng');
    $this->db->from('question');
    $query=$this->db->get();
    foreach($query->result_array() as $result)
    {
        print_r($result);
    }
    die;
    $this->load->view('admin/redeem');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

remove `die;` at all, also why you print result you should pass it to your view then read in view:

```
function redeem()
{
    $this->db->select('questionEng');
    $this->db->from('question');
    $query=$this->db->get();
    $arr_data = $query->result_array() ;
    $this->load->view('admin/redeem', $arr_data);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    public function REDEEM()
    $this->db->select('questionEng' );  
    $this->db->from('question');
    $this->db->where(select any colum you want);
    $query=$this->db->get();
    $list=$query->result();
    return $list;
```

Then load the model in controller as
 $res = $this->your model name->REDEEM();
echo json_encode($res);exit; or load view in place of json

Answer (score 0):

You can do this.

```
function redeem()
{
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('question');
    $query=$this->db->get();
    $results  =  $query->result_array();

        echo "<pre>";
        print_r($results); // to print results
        echo "<pre>"; 


    $this->load->view('admin/redeem',$results); //pass to view
}
```